# Geometry of finitely generated convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

After drawing some pictures, I guess the following is true: Let $y_{1},\ldots, y_{d}$ be points in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ (the Euclidean norm is denoted by $\left\Vert \, \cdot \, \right\Vert$) and let $C = {\operatorname{conv}}{\left\{y_{1},\ldots,y_{d} \right\}}$ be the convex hull of those points. Assume that $0 \in C$. Then there is $r >0$ such that $$\left\{ \lambda x : x \in C \text{ and } \lambda >0 \text{ such that } \left\Vert \lambda x \right\Vert \leq r \right\} \subset C.$$

Here is my question: Is the above property correct? If so, could you please give me some clues?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Given that $0\in C$, you can use convexity to show that $\{ \lambda x : x \in C \text{ and } \lambda \in [0,1]\} \subset C$. From here just take $r=\min\{|x|:x\in C\}$.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Could you please specify why choosing $r = \max\left\{ \left\Vert  x \right\Vert : x \in C  \right\}$ works?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to take the min. The reason is it'll make your $|\lambda x|\leq r$ set a subset of the $[0,1]x$ set, which is itself a subset of $C$.

Comment: I understand that the minimum is achieved in our case, but it's $0$ since $0 \in C$.  Am I correct?